# Tasks on asio::strand are running on a single thread

Tags: c++, asio, stdasync

I modified an asio strand example using the standalone version of the library from [4a here](https://www.gamedev.net/blogs/entry/2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace util
{
static std::mutex s_mtx_print;

// Default argument value
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments
template <typename... Args>
void sync_print(const bool log_thread_id, Args &&... args)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> print_lock(s_mtx_print);
    if (log_thread_id)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] ";
    }
    (std::cout << ... << args) << '\n';
}

}

void Worker(std::unique_ptr<asio::io_service> &ios)
{
    util::sync_print(true, " Started...");
    if(ios) {ios->run();}
    util::sync_print(true, " End");
}

void PrintNum(int n)
{
    std::cout << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] " << n << '\n';
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(300ms);
}

void OrderedInvocation(std::unique_ptr<asio::io_service::strand> &up_strand)
{
    if(up_strand)
    {
        up_strand->post(std::bind(&PrintNum, 1));
        up_strand->post(std::bind(&PrintNum, 2));
        up_strand->post(std::bind(&PrintNum, 3));
        up_strand->post(std::bind(&PrintNum, 4));
        up_strand->post(std::bind(&PrintNum, 5));
        up_strand->post(std::bind(&PrintNum, 6));
        up_strand->post(std::bind(&PrintNum, 7));
        up_strand->post(std::bind(&PrintNum, 8));
        up_strand->post(std::bind(&PrintNum, 9));
    }
    else{
        std::cerr << "Invalid strand" << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    util::sync_print(true, "section 4 started ...");
    auto up_ios = std::make_unique<asio::io_service>();
    auto up_work = std::make_unique<asio::io_service::work>(*up_ios);
    auto up_strand = std::make_unique<asio::io_service::strand>(*up_ios);

    std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks;
    constexpr int NUM_TASK = 3;

    for(int i = 0; i< NUM_TASK; ++i)
    {
        tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &Worker, std::ref(up_ios)));
    }
    std::cout << "Task size " << tasks.size() << '\n';
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
    OrderedInvocation(up_strand);

    up_work.reset();

    for(auto &t: tasks){ t.get(); }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is: when I run the code, it appears that the function PrintNum only runs on a single thread

as the console output is

```
[140180645058368] section 4 started ...
Task size 3
[140180610144000]  Started...
[140180626929408]  Started...
[140180618536704]  Started...
[140180610144000] 1
[140180610144000] 2
[140180610144000] 3
[140180610144000] 4
[140180610144000] 5
[140180610144000] 6
[140180610144000] 7
[140180610144000] 8
[140180610144000] 9
[140180610144000]  End
[140180626929408]  End
[140180618536704]  End
```

My question is, do I need to configure the strand to let the tasks spread to all threads? Or maybe I missed something here?

**[Edit]**
Ideally, the output should be something like

```
[00154F88] The program will exit when all work has finished.
[001532B0] Thread Start
[00154FB0] Thread Start
[001532B0] x: 1
[00154FB0] x: 2
[001532B0] x: 3
[00154FB0] x: 4
[001532B0] x: 5
[00154FB0] Thread Finish
[001532B0] Thread Finish
Press any key to continue . . .
```

In the expected output, both thread `00154FB0` and `001532B0` executed the PrintNum(), but in the modified version, only one thread executed the PrintNum().

If the strand is not been used, the output is:

```
[140565152012096] section 4 started ...
[140565133883136]  Started...
Task size 3
[140565117097728]  Started...
[140565125490432]  Started...
[[140565133883136] [140565117097728]] 12

3
[140565133883136] [4
[140565117097728140565125490432] 6
] 5
[140565133883136] 7
[140565125490432] 8
[140565117097728] 9
[140565125490432]  End
[140565117097728]  End
[140565133883136]  End
```

Thanks

Here is the cpu info from the machine I am using

```
$lscpu
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
```

The OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Rong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the purpose of a [strand](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html):

> *A strand is defined as a strictly sequential invocation of event handlers (i.e. no concurrent invocation). Use of strands allows execution of code in a multithreaded program without the need for explicit locking (e.g. using mutexes).*

If you want parallel invocation, you will need to remove the strand, `post()` directly to `io_service` and invoke `io_service::run` from a number of threads (you're doing that already).

An unrelated note: there is no point in passing unique pointers around; make your life easier and just pass raw pointers or references.

Comment: My understand is unique_ptr should be almost zero cost~ is that right?

Comment: My understand is, the io_service should run the PrintNum in the same order but across different thread, it is also explained in the original artical. Although that article is pretty old. The asio implementation might change over the time. I updated the output when the strand is removed

Comment: Got you, you are absolutely right about less code is better :)

Comment: From your linked article: *work will still execute serially, but it will execute through whichever worker thread is available at the time*. Serially means one at a time.

Comment: I would say that there are two other threads available in my situation. Since all thread threads were already started. In the linked article, the strand runs cross two threads. I copied the output. Both thread  `00154FB0` and `001532B0` were invoking the function PrintNum(). 'Serially', in this context, would be in the same order as of how the function pushed into the strand. I know the strand does not guarantee to run all tasks in all three threads. But to run all tasks in one thread would make the whole io_service and strand thing completely pointless, right?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late. However, I ran into the same issue, following the same example as above. It turns out the current way of using a `strand` is a bit different, as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66765121/14078020). Here is my revision on the original code:

```
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/post.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/executor_work_guard.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
std::mutex global_stream_lock;

void
worker_thread(std::shared_ptr<asio::io_context> ioc) {
    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] Thread start"
              << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();
    ioc->run();
    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] Thread finished"
              << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();
}

void
print_num(int x) {
    std::cout << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] x = " << x
              << std::endl;
}

int
main() {
    auto ioc = std::make_shared<asio::io_context>();
    auto strand = asio::make_strand(*ioc);
    auto work = asio::make_work_guard(*ioc);
    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id()
              << "] This thread will exit when all work is finished "
              << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();

    std::vector<std::thread> thread_group;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        thread_group.emplace_back(std::bind(worker_thread, ioc));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        asio::post(strand, std::bind(print_num, 2 * i + 1));
        asio::post(strand, std::bind(print_num, 2 * i + 2));
    }


    work.reset();
    for (auto &t : thread_group) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
[139877509977920] This thread will exit when all work is finished 
[139877509973568] Thread start
[139877501580864] Thread start
[139877493188160] Thread start
[139877484795456] Thread start
[139877509973568] x = 1
[139877509973568] x = 2
[139877493188160] x = 3
[139877493188160] x = 4
[139877501580864] x = 5
[139877501580864] x = 6
[139877484795456] x = 7
[139877484795456] x = 8
[139877509973568] Thread finished
[139877493188160] Thread finished
[139877484795456] Thread finished
[139877501580864] Thread finished
```